# SQL : in clause in stored procedure:how to pass values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to write a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure which will select and return the user records from the user table for some userids which are passed to the stored procedure as parameter.

How to do this ?

I can pass the user ids as a string separated by comma. So that I can use the

```
select * 
from users 
where userid in (userids)
```

E.g. : I want to select records for id's 5,6,7,8,9

How to write the stored procedure ?

Comment: This is a common question. I have an option here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977021/can-a-stored-procedure-have-dynamic-parameters-to-be-used-in-an-in-clause/977114#977114

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005, check out Erland Sommarskog's excellent [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) article which shows some techniques how to deal with lists and arrays in SQL Server 2005 (he also has another article for SQL Server 2000).

If you could upgrade to SQL Server 2008, you can use the new feature called "table valued parameter":

First, create a user-defined table type

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyUserIDs AS TABLE (UserID INT NOT NULL)
```

Secondly, use that table type in your stored procedure as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROC proc_GetUsers @UserIDTable MyUserIDs READONLY 
AS
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users
    WHERE userid IN (SELECT UserID FROM @UserIDTable)
```

See details [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters).

Marc

Answer (score 10):

Just use it like this will work

```
Create procedure sp_DoctorList 
@userid varchar(100)
as 
begin
exec ('select * from doctor where userid in ( '+ @userid +' )')
end
```

Comment: Thanks for advice mate ! Just **exec** part worked for me in my procedure `insert into #temp_hourly exec ('select ZONE_ID from ZONE where ZONE_ID in (' + @ZoneId + ') group by ZONE_ID')`

Answer (score 6):

you could use dynamic sql. Pass the in statement to a Sql SP via a variable and concatenate it  into a query in the SQL and execute using sp_execute sql

```
create procedure myproc(@clause varchar(100)) as 
begin
  exec sp_executesql 'select * from users where userid in ( ' + @clause +' )'
end
```

Comment: works, but dynamic SQL has its share of problems (security, performance etc.)

Answer (score 5):

see [my previous answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456192/comparing-a-column-to-a-list-of-values-in-t-sql/1456404#1456404)

this is the best source:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

create a split function, and use it like:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable  y
    INNER JOIN dbo.splitFunction(@Parameter) s ON y.ID=s.Value
```

[I prefer the number table approach](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum)

For this method to work, you need to do this one time table setup:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
ALTER TABLE Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Once the Numbers table is set up, create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ListToTable]
(
     @SplitOn  char(1)      --REQUIRED, the character to split the @List string on
    ,@List     varchar(8000)--REQUIRED, the list to split apart
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(

    ----------------
    --SINGLE QUERY-- --this will not return empty rows
    ----------------
    SELECT
        ListValue
        FROM (SELECT
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(List2, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, List2, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
                  FROM (
                           SELECT @SplitOn + @List + @SplitOn AS List2
                       ) AS dt
                      INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.Number < LEN(dt.List2)
                  WHERE SUBSTRING(List2, number, 1) = @SplitOn
             ) dt2
        WHERE ListValue IS NOT NULL AND ListValue!=''

);
GO
```

You can now easily split a CSV string into a table and join on it:

```
select * from dbo.FN_ListToTable(',','1,2,3,,,4,5,6777,,,')
```

OUTPUT:

```
ListValue
-----------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6777

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Your can pass in a CSV string into a procedure and process only rows for the given IDs:

```
SELECT
    y.*
    FROM YourTable y
        INNER JOIN dbo.FN_ListToTable(',',@GivenCSV) s ON y.ID=s.ListValue
```

Comment: I admit I have been using this for several years now, but it came back to bite me in the ass. The chunking multi-statement version of this (here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum ) is indeed twice faster. The problem was only noticeable when the involved table contained close to a million rows. So take that into consideration before you use @KM's solution.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming T-SQL, you can use this nice function (that returns a table).

```
DROP FUNCTION sp_ConvertStringToTable
GO
CREATE FUNCTION sp_ConvertStringToTable(@list ntext)
      RETURNS @tbl TABLE (Position INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                          Value INT NOT NULL) AS
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @pos      int,
              @textpos  int,
              @chunklen smallint,
              @str      nvarchar(4000),
              @tmpstr   nvarchar(4000),
              @leftover nvarchar(4000)

      SET @textpos = 1
      SET @leftover = ''
      WHILE @textpos <= datalength(@list) / 2
      BEGIN
         SET @chunklen = 4000 - datalength(@leftover) / 2
         SET @tmpstr = ltrim(@leftover + substring(@list, @textpos, @chunklen))
         SET @textpos = @textpos + @chunklen

         SET @pos = charindex(' ', @tmpstr)
         WHILE @pos > 0
         BEGIN
            SET @str = substring(@tmpstr, 1, @pos - 1)
            INSERT @tbl (Value) VALUES(convert(int, @str))
            SET @tmpstr = ltrim(substring(@tmpstr, @pos + 1, len(@tmpstr)))
            SET @pos = charindex(' ', @tmpstr)
         END

         SET @leftover = @tmpstr
      END

      IF ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)) <> ''
         INSERT @tbl (Value) VALUES(convert(int, @leftover))

      RETURN
   END   
GO
```

In this way:

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE userid IN 
( SELECT Value FROM sp_ConvertStringToTable('1 2 3') )
```

You can change the stored function to work with comma separated strings instead of space separated ones.

If you don't want / can't use a stored function you can include the code of it inside the stored procedure where needed.

EDIT: this is incredibly more performant than the string concatenation.

Comment: Do you have stats about that? I'd be interested in reading them

Comment: this is slow, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456192/comparing-a-column-to-a-list-of-values-in-t-sql/1456404#1456404

Comment: Woah! Thank you KM, doing a couple of tests and replacing it to project now!

Anyways, my "this is faster" was meant referring to dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2):

try this this works for me

```
DECLARE @InClause NVARCHAR(100)
SET @InClause = 'tom,dick,harry'
DECLARE @SafeInClause NVARCHAR(100)
SET @SafeInClause = ',' + @InClause + ',' 
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE PATINDEX(',' + myColumn + ',', @SafeInClause) > 0
```

Comment: This worked well although I had to change `',' + myColumn + ','` to `'%,' + myColumn + ',%'` for it to match when there was more than one entry in the list.

Comment: with this I get Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectUsers (@UserIds VARCHAR(8000))
AS
SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE userid IN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@UserIds, ','))
```

```
EXEC SelectUsers @UserIds = 'a1b2,c3d4,e5f6'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc  
     @intList varchar(MAX)  
AS  
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM dbo.users
     WHERE userid IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@intList, ','))  
END
```

To execute it:

```
Exec MyProc @intList = '5, 6, 7, 8, 9'
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -3):

You can also use Find_IN_SET instead of IN. See the query below

```
create procedure myproc(IN in_user_ids varchar(100)) 
begin
   select * from users where FIND_IN_SET(userid, in_user_ids);
end
```

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` is not a SQL standard function, and it's **not** available in Microsoft **SQL Server** (that the OP was asking about)