# Cast integer column to varchar and compare with string

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I compare list of integers with integer columns in sql server. For example I have a column `statusid` as `int`. I want to get the result where `statusid` in `1,4,8,9`. I kept all these integers in string and operate with the column statusid  as below but i am facing error there. This string may be hard coded or parameter.

```
where Cast(statusid as varchar) in ('1,4,8,9');
```

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: "I kept all these integers in string" Do you see the problem? Use a table with foreign-keys instead.

Comment: Where does your string of numbers come from?

Comment: @Westie : its a parameter

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525126/sql-in-clause-in-storedprocedurehow-to-pass-values).

Comment: See conversion functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a87d0850-c670-4720-9ad5-6f5a22343ea8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

since the number are converted to string, the values on `IN` clause should each be wrap with single quotes

```
where Cast(statusid as varchar(20)) in ('1','4','8','9');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am taking all the integers in the string. How it can be taken here...

Comment: can you expand this more, *taking all the integers in the string*?

Comment: I want to search over the collection of integer values like 1,2,5 and so on. So I keep all required numbers(1,2,5..) in a string like '1,2,5' and want to compare like `where Cast(statusid as varchar) in ('1,2,5');`

Comment: unfortunately, you have to do some extra work. you need to create a user define function that breaks `'1,2,5'` into pieces so the value each values can be compared to you list of ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE statusid 
IN (1, 4, 8, 9);
```

Comment: I think with this solution it may depend on exactly where eraj is getting his list of numbers from - seems like an incomplete question from eraj to me.