# How to pass string array in 'In' clause in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have user table in database storing user information. I want to create stored procedure in which I will pass UserIDs as a list. I want to use this list to fetch data from user table.

I am creating type as a table using following query:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyUserIDs AS TABLE (UserID int)
```

Now I am using this type in stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_in_Query]
    @MyUserids MyUserIDs READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * From Tbl_UserMast where UserID in (select UserID from @MyUserids)
END
```

When I execute this code I am getting following error:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with MyUserIDs

I am following this link as a reference:
[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525126/sql-in-clause-in-stored-procedurehow-to-pass-values)

I am directly executing stored procedure in sql server
[image]

Comment: Good question. Can you also provide an example of how you *call* the procedure, so that we have a [mcve]?

Comment: Use Table Valued Parameters.

Comment: Sorry, what do use mean by "Use Table Valued Parameters"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a TVP-value using the SSMS gui (or at least I'm not aware of how to do it), but you have to do it in t-sql code, like so:

```
-- declare a variable using the user-defined type
DECLARE @MyUsers MyUserIDs 

-- insert some data into it
INSERT INTO @MyUsers(UserID) VALUES (1),(2),(4) 

-- and pass it into the proc
EXEC Test_in_Query @MyUserids = @MyUsers
```

Comment: Ok. That's work. My SP was correct. Just passing the value wrongly. Thank you for your help.