# how to pass a value dynamically in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

how to pass parameter values at run time in stored proc.

for ex: when i try to pass the start date and end date the values are not being passed, is there any way to pass the value something like '?' in T-SQL.

```
exec SP '01-01-2011','01-30-2011'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of resources out there. Just using google I found several articles including a question here on SO.

[Can a stored procedure have dynamic parameters to be used in an "IN" clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977021/can-a-stored-procedure-have-dynamic-parameters-to-be-used-in-an-in-clause)

[T-SQL Stored Procedures Using Parameters](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7132.asp)

If you post some your stored procedure, then it will give a better idea of your code.

Here is an example from the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployees 
    @LastName nvarchar(50), 
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) 
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT FirstName, LastName,Department
    FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName;
GO
```

Then executing it

```
EXECUTE HumanResources.uspGetEmployees N'Ackerman', N'Pilar';
-- Or
EXEC HumanResources.uspGetEmployees @LastName = N'Ackerman', @FirstName = N'Pilar';
GO
-- Or
EXECUTE HumanResources.uspGetEmployees @FirstName = N'Pilar', @LastName = N'Ackerman';
GO
-- Or, if this procedure is the first statement within a batch:
HumanResources.uspGetEmployees N'Ackerman', N'Pilar';
```