# writing stored procedure to select values from one column based on input parameter refering to another column of the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with two columns projectIDS and ServiceIDS. Each project will have a set of services. Now I have to write a procedure to get common services for a list of projectIDs I pass as a parameter.
i.e., suppose i have

```
                             PID      SID
                             ---      ---
                              1         1
                              1         2
                              1         3
                              2         1
                              2         2
                              3         1
                              3         3
```

Now if i pass PIDs (1,2,3) as input parameter i should get SID = 1 as output since it is common for all projects.
thank you

Comment: Downvoting for lack of research effort. Typically a question will reflect some variation of "I tried it this way and that doesn't work. How can I do it right/do it better?"

Comment: You've got a lot of questions rolled into one.   First, stored procedures require a set list of inputs, are you saying there is only 3 inputs to the storedproc you are making, or do you want it to accept a dynamic number of entries?  if the latter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977021/can-a-stored-procedure-have-dynamic-parameters-to-be-used-in-an-in-clause    the SQL to see if there is a common 'SID' between a list of PID's is actually pretty straight forward using some aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is find records where a whole set is matched.

Lets assume you have this set in a table, link this to your source table, this excludes PIDs that aren't in your set.

Then count the number of matches for each SID. If the number of PIDs for a SID equals the number of PIDs in your set then you have a match.

```
SELECT Sid
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Sid
HAVING Count(DISTINCT Pid) = 3
```