# dataSet.xsd query select where in

Tags: sql, select, dataset

In SQL it works fine

```
SELECT NOID, NO_DOSSOIN, NO_ORDO, POSOLOG FROM dbo.ESPMEDS_ORDO_SORTIR
WHERE NO_DOSSOIN = @NO_DOSSOIN AND NOID IN (@NOIDIN)
```

example

```
SELECT NOID, NO_DOSSOIN, NO_ORDO, POSOLOG FROM dbo.ESPMEDS_ORDO_SORTIR
WHERE NO_DOSSOIN = 10 AND NOID IN (16,17)
```

But as I put this in a dataset.xsd query I don't get the same output, I cannot put more than one id into NOIDIN parameter because the NOID type is integer

so  my file DataSet.xsd only work like this:
[image: Dataset.xsd File]
    SELECT NOID, NO_DOSSOIN, NO_ORDO, POSOLOG FROM dbo.ESPMEDS_ORDO_SORTIR
    WHERE NO_DOSSOIN = 10 AND NOID IN (16)

the error says I cannot convert data from string to int

[image: The Structure]

Comment: Peu tu nous montrer la structure de la table `dbo.ESPMEDS_ORDO_SORTIR` pour voir quel sont les types de donnés ?

Comment: I'm not forbidding you from using languages other than English on here, but it's not ideal to have non-English discussions in StackOverflow questions. It may be better to have a non-English discussion in chat, then post your finding in English here. Please take a look at this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: *** Can you show the `dbo.ESPMEDS_ORDO_SORTIR` table design so we can see the DataTypes

Answer (score 0):

You should just separate the `NOIDIN`. Don't expect to be able to pass an `Int32` that looks like `16,17` it will always be seen as a string by this wizard and won't compile at all if you execute it from the code.

[image]

The easiest option for you is to pass the range in two values like this :

`SELECT NOID, NO_DOSSOIN, NO_ORDO, POSOLOG FROM dbo.ESPMEDS_ORDO_SORTIR
WHERE NO_DOSSOIN = @NO_DOSSOIN AND NOID IN (@NOIDSTART, @NOIDEND)`

And then assign :

`@NOIDSTART = 16`

`@NOIDEND = 17`

If you're parameters are dynamic you should read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977021/can-a-stored-procedure-have-dynamic-parameters-to-be-used-in-an-in-clause) which pretty much covers the subject.

Comment: Thanks you for your respond, but it is dynamic sometimes only 2 data 16,17 sometime 3 data 16,15,20 or maybe 10 data or more

Comment: I updated my answer. To forget to mark the question as answered if you found what you were looking for :-)